# Did Stack Overflow update their Cookie or Privacy policy or Terms of Service?

Tags: support, terms-of-service

I just saw the "you agree to our terms by using the site" banner while browsing the site today:

[image]

A few other users I polled on chat have seen it this morning or yesterday. Is this a bug, or did Stack Overflow update these policies recently?

If the latter, shouldn't the banner indicate that they've changed, rather than act like it's a first-time acceptance?

Comment: How can something extra information can be a bug? Also any updates to policy will be known by us as they say it in their policy. Any updates to it and we will be informed

Comment: @window.document If the banner appeared when there was no update/change to the policies, then it is a bug; I have already acknowledged and closed the banner in the past.

Comment: @window.document that's what *should* happen, but the whole point of this question is to figure out if the policy did change without announcement or if that message was incorrectly shown due to a bug.

Comment: Maybe i’m wrong but that does not say that it changed. Can i know how can we conclude that the policy was changed from the bug or the screenshot? Or when they change it they display a banner? If they do when they change the policy then it is obvious that it changed

Comment: The Privacy Policy and Terms of Services pages have a "Last Updated" date at the bottom. Not sure why the Cookie Policy doesn't.

Comment: @window.document That's exactly the point of this question. And it's actually *not* obvious that they changed it by showing this banner, because the banner doesn't indicate a change.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

We did not update the policy or ToS. Periodically we need to re-verify consent for  e-privacy and GDPR and when this was setup, we guessed a year as the time needed to re-verify. It's been a year since this was rolled out...that means it's time to consent again.

Really, it's Nick's fault because we were supposed to check with legal on the timeframe and never did:

[image: Who is to blame]

Basically, we need to check with legal and get this updated.

Comment: IIRC you can make the build fail if there are `//TODO`s left in the code base. Maybe propose that in the next dev call .... ;)

Comment: `// TODO` found 771 times...

Comment: The exact value is 365, more or less 6 to 8.

Comment: Thanks for the response; can you adjust/add the wording to indicate that periodic re-acknowledgement is required? For those of us who live outside the jurisdiction of GDPR (most SO users, I think), it is probably not obvious that it's predicated on a regular renewal of informed consent.

Comment: @TylerH Made a slight edit, clearer now?

Comment: @Taryn Er, I mean in the acknowledgement banner, not this answer... :-)

Comment: @TylerH Ah, my mistake. I'll ask about it or you can request it via a feature-request then we have the request somewhere  ;)

Comment: @Taryn I'll keep my fingers crossed it'll happen and then maybe remember in a year (or whatever legal decides) when we see the banner again :-)

Comment: @DeanWard `git blame --line-porcelain --contains TODO | sed -n 's/^author //p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn` Nick Craver 771

Comment: I find it interesting how you state in your comments that it is "1 year", but then shows code that only states "365 days", it should be 365.241 days for a year

Comment: @DeanWard I guess your coding policy is to resolve all TODOs in 6 to 8 weeks? (FWIW, I'd recommend using an issue tracker for anything you have to remember past the current commit)

Comment: @Ferrybig Calculating the time in a year can be [complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453208/how-can-i-calculate-the-age-of-a-person-in-year-month-days) -- that's why in the overwhelming majority of cases, people accept that 1 year = 365 days for whatever their context is.